# How do I compare the tokenized line with the str "exit"?

Tags: c

I don't know how to compare the line to the word "exit" so that when the keyboard input is exit then the program will exit.
    #define MAX_LINE 4096
    #define MAX_WORDS MAX_LINE/2

```
int main()
{
        char line[MAX_LINE], *words[MAX_WORDS], message[MAX_LINE];
        int stop=0,nwords=0;

        while(1)
        {
                printf("OSP CLI $ ");
        fgets(line,MAX_LINE,stdin);

        if(strcmp(line,"exit")==0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }   
void tokenize(char *line, char **words, int *nwords)
{
    *nwords=1;
    for(words[0]=strtok(line," \t\n");
       (*nwords<MAX_WORDS)&&(words[*nwords]=strtok(NULL, " \t\n"));
        *nwords=*nwords+1
    ); /* empty body */
    return;
}
```

The code is correct but I do not know what it does. So the for(words[0]=strtok(line," \t\n"); reads the first word in the line. "line" is keyboard input that the user types in at runtime which is just a string like: hello world blah dee doo. But after that the next line with nwords<..... don't understand anything after the line with the for.

Comment: It breaks down `line` into tokens and puts these in `words`

Comment: Take a debugger and step through it. That will show you what is happening.

Comment: Like lets say if line is

Comment: Where do I find a debugger?

Comment: Looks like you need to study two things: what `strtok` does, and what `for` loop does. Also, note that assignment operator `=` returns the value of the left operand after the assignment takes place. That way `operator=` can be used inside a condition.

Comment: debugger should be part of your development environment and probably packed with your compiler.

Comment: Can you go more in depth? I know what it does but I don't know what each part means alone. So I can only use the code because I know what it does but I can't reproduce the code from scratch because I don't understand each part of it alone.

Comment: I am using notepad on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Not an integrated development environment because the lecturer doesn't allow it.

Comment: The for loop doesn't have a body which just totally makes me confused.

Comment: But the `for` loop does have all the other usual elements: initialiser, condition, post-step. So these get executed normally.

Comment: I just checked out the strtok() function and I know what it does now. I just don't understand the logic of the loop now. Is there even a loop? When i did java last semester it was like for(int i=0; i<9;i++){

Comment: So when I called the tokenize(line,words,*nword); I will then use if(strcmp(line,"exit")==0){exit(0);}. Does that make sense? I am comparing the line to exit but ain't I supposed to compare the tokenized line to exit?

Answer (score 3):

```
for (a; b; c) d;
```

Can be translated into:

```
a;
while (b) {
   d;
   c;
}
```

So:

```
void tokenize(char *line, char **words, int *nwords)
{
    *nwords=1;
    for(words[0]=strtok(line," \t\n");
       (*nwords<MAX_WORDS)&&(words[*nwords]=strtok(NULL, " \t\n"));
        *nwords=*nwords+1
    ); /* empty body */
    return;
}
```

can be translated into (with some other improvements, ex. `int *a; if (a)` is same as `int *a; if (a != NULL)`):

```
void tokenize(char *line, char **words, int *nwords)
{
    *nwords = 1;
    words[0] = strtok(line, " \t\n");
    while ( 
             *nwords < MAX_WORDS && 
             (words[*nwords] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")) != NULL
    ) {
        /* empty body */
        *nwords = *nwords + 1;
    }
}
```

let's verbose it a bit more:

```
void tokenize(char *line, char **words, int *nwords)
{
    *nwords = 1;
    words[0] = strtok(line, " \t\n");
    while (*nwords < MAX_WORDS) {
        words[*nwords] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        if (words[*nwords] == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        /* empty body */
        *nwords = *nwords + 1;
    }
}
```

This function is dangerous or probably a part of something bigger (does not check if arguments are null and omits if line is empty).

`words` is a pointer, it's an array of `char*` pointers. The length of the `words` pointer seems to be at least `MAX_WORDS` long. `nwords` is a pointer to the returned length of the `words` pointer. The caller expects this function to fill `words` memory and `nwords` memory with tokens from the string. It is assumed that all pointers are not NULL and valid, `MAX_WORDS > 0` and `strlen(line) != 0` or that the string `line` does not consist only of `" \t\n"` delimiters we use, so that there is always a first token.

- First the `nwords` is initialized with `1`, and first token is extracted `words[0] = strtok(line, " \t\n");`.
- Then until the number of tokens is lower then `MAX_WORDS` the next token is extracted `words[*nwords] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")`
- From `strtok` manual - the returned value from `strtok` is "NULL if there are no more tokens". If `strtok` returns NULL, means we finished th string - so we return from the function.
- If however the number of tokens is lower then `MAX_WORDS` and we extracted the next valid token, we increase the count `*nwords = *nwords + 1;`
- The caller is left with `words` initialized with pointers inside `line` string, the memory behind `nwords` is initialized with the count of tokens and the `line` array is modified to have terminating zeros `'\0'` in place of token delimeters.

Comment: Thanks for the help you made it so much easier, I didn't understand that for loop because this is only my second semester in programming, I went from java to operating systems programming with c.

Comment: whew a big headache.

Answer (score 2):

Let's re-write the code to be less terse and more readable:

```
void tokenize(char *line, char **words, int *nwords)
{
  *nwords=1;
  words[0]=strtok(line," \t\n");
  while (*nwords < MAX_WORDS) {
    words[*nwords] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    if (!words[*nwords])
      break;
    *nwords = *nwords + 1;
  }
}
```

One thing which also makes this code a bit harder to understand is the fact that it always accesses the number of words indirectly, via the `nwords` pointer. Here's one more rewrite, without this shorthand:

```
void tokenize(char *line, char **words, int *nwords)
{
  int wordCount = 1;
  words[0]=strtok(line," \t\n");
  while (wordCount < MAX_WORDS) {
    words[wordCount] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    if (!words[wordCount])
      break;
    wordCount = wordCount + 1;
  }
  *nwords = wordCount;
}
```

Finally, for a pointer `p`, testing `!p` is the same as testing `p == NULL`. So the check `if (!words[wordCount])` means "if the currently last element in `words` is a null pointer." That can happen when `strtok` returns a null pointer, indicating it has finished parsing.

Hopefully, it's a bit clearer now.

In general, the function uses `strtok` to extract words from `line` and store them into successive elements of the array `words`, with the number of words stored returned in `nwords`.

It will repeatedly extract one word, store it, and increment the word count. This continues until either:

- `MAX_WORDS` are extracted, or
- `strtok` returns a null pointer, meaning there are no more words left in `line`.

Comment: if (!words[*nwords])
      break; I don't know what that means?

Comment: Well !words[*nwords]) I am confused about that.

Comment: @JustinZhao I've expanded the answer a bit; is it clear now?